# Azure Application Insights and Web Site projects

Tags: asp.net, azure, vs-web-site-project, azure-application-insights

Is it possible to add Application Insights to a Web Site project type?

In Visual Studio, the following context menu is available for Web Application projects but is missing for Web Site projects.

[image]

Comment: That would seem to be yet another reason to not use web site "projects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to share what I ended up with doing. First of all, it seems to work like a charm.

The Application Insight is implemented as an ASP.NET Module, so in order to hook it up for Web Site project you need to do the following:

1. Add `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web` NuGet package
2. Register AI module in `web.config`

   ```
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
     <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
   </modules>
   ```
3. Make sure you have `ApplicationInsights.config` in Web Site base directory (along with `web.config`) - it defines which telemetry you going to be collecting

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to instrument a Web Site project with Application Insights manually. Here are the [instructions](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-start-monitoring-app-health-usage/).

Comment: Not helpful as the question clearly is about Website project in Visual Studio and not a Web Application (csproj). Shared link has instructions about csproj